# React Native: Can you get the dimensions of an element using a ref?

Tags: react-native

Is there an api to get the height and width of an element in React Native using a ref?

I'm not interested in the window or screen dimensions, and I understand you can use onLayout, but wanted to double check to make sure there's no api for height and width when using a ref.

---

Some additional verbose elaboration:

In ReactJS, `clientHeight` and `clientWidth` works, but not in React Native.

```js
const ref = React.useRef();
const height = ref.current.clientHeight;
const width= ref.current.clientWidth;

return <div ref={ref} />;
```

On React Native, you can use onLayout, but is there a method for a ref?

```js
<View
  onLayout={(event) => {
    const dimensions = event.nativeEvent.layout;
    const {width, height} = dimensions;
  }}
>
</View>
```